# Is there any way to tell Cygwin to look for Python in default location?

Tags: python-3.x, cygwin

I had python, but I need python installed via Cygwin (for uwsgi). I installed Cygwin and then Python but Cygwin decided to use my Window's Python instead of Cygwin's, (Tried `which python` and it showed me wrong Python), so I uninstalled python that was on windows, python that was on cygwin and cygwin, and installed again cygwin + python, but now `which python` tells me that there is no Python in dir where was window's python, but why it doesn't look in Cygwin's default python dir?
So now I have 2 options:
a) Uninstall again Cygwin with Python, but this time completely with all reg files and other junk to remove old path, and install it all over again. (but I have no clue, where is that file with info of python's paths)
b) Somehow tell Cygwin to look for Python in /bin/python3.8/exe or /lib/python3.8 (don't know which one Cygwin want)
Thank you for your advice and your time.

Comment: All I can say is make sure there's nothing weird going on with your `$PATH`. Cygwin should always have something like `/bin:/usr/bin` first so if you have Python installed it will be there.

Comment: Instead of `python --version` or `python3 --version` I suppose to write `python3.8 --version` and everything works, funny, totally my mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

currently on Cygwin, python is a symlink to python2

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 Marco Kein 13 May 23 17:18 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7.exe
```

if you install the python3 package version 3.8.3-1
the python3 symlink will point to python3.8

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 Marco Kein 13 Jun 20 06:27 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.8.exe
```

Comment: It's kinda odd, because when I had "windows Python", in Cygwin terminal I tried `which python3` and `python3 -v` and  got `no python3` but `which python` showed me correct way to "windows Python" that was 3.7 (Python inside Cygwin had same version 3.7, but somehow Cygwin decided to work with Python that I installed before in windows, instead that one, that I installed with Cygwin). Thank you.